# best strategy for multiple insertions in db from one file

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Let me clarify the title of the question.

I'm implementing a web application's back-end.

This is what I will like to create in one single `.html` file

- User inserts point,line or polygon on a map.
- User fills a form with text data. This data are relative to the
  geometry she inserted on the map.
- User uploads photos and videos via html5 websockets/drag'n'drop.
  Those are also relative with the geometry she inserted on the map.

There is only one button at the bottom of the page, named "Save All" that saves all those data at once on the database (insert).

The problem? I have two seperate tables in the database. One is named "pins" and will get the geometry data and the form data.

The other is named "multimedia" and will get the images/videos.

Now "multimedia" has a column named "multipin" that contains a "pins" id, so I can relate pins and multimedia.

All the columns containig ids are "SERIAL" (with each insertion, id automatically grows +1).

I was thinking that if I do both the insertions at the same time there is no way I can get the new "pins" id and insert it to the "multipin" column of "multimedia". I have to wait for the new "pins" id to be created and then insert it to "multipin".

So, two insertions (?)
The solution I came up with is creating three `html`  files. On the first, user inserts geometry and form data. Hits a button named "Click here to add multimedia". Now this button sends the data to another file that inserts in the "pins" and gets the new id. Redirects to the third file and also sends the new "pins".  So now user can insert photo/video and the code knows the "pins" id , so can put it in "multipin".

Does this sounds fine? Is there a better way or strategy?

For the "save all at once" version I was thinking websockets...For the "3 files version" ? Should I use "traditional" ajax and websockets just for the multimedia?

I apologize for the big question. And my English (not my native language)

Thank you for your time

slevin

Answer (score 0):

Save all at once is a better strategy for the user.

Assuming you're using a transactional relational database, you can save everything the following way.

- Insert your pins table data.
- Commit
- Get the pins sequential id
- Insert your multimedia
- Commit

If there's any problem with the multimedia, you would rollback the multimedia inserts and delete the pins table data row to keep database consistency.

Comment: Is postgresql/postGIS transactional database?

Comment: Sorry to bother again. The steps you mention look like the "multiple files" way. How can I have 2 different commits, on the same file? And the first commit always have to happen first... Thanks again

Comment: @slevin: You either write program code to execute multiple SQL statements, or you write an SQL stored procedure to execute multiple SQL statements.  Either way, you have to execute multiple SQL statements in the order I gave in the answer.